# Memory Retention : isolated information vs emphasized information in a heap

Tags: memory, long-term-memory

I have observed that when learning new words (vocabulary building), if we are presented with, say, 5 new words in these 2 manners:

1. only 5 words presented in isolation
2. 40 words presented, with 5 words emphasized

then, the retention of those 5 words is more in the second case.

Similarly, if we are studying some subject, and we are presented with a summary of important points in one case, and a collection of several points with important points underlined, then there is more retention in the second case.

To generalize the observation: **Memory retention is more if information is presented accentuated among a heap of other information, than when it is presented in isolation**.

Is my observation correct? Have other people witnessed it in some form? And why does this happen?

Further, can someone point me to some references if research has been done on this? I couldn't think of a keyword to search for this on the web.